# Weird message when I try to join MC Central (MiniGames Server)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have been playing on this server (MC Central a dedicated MiniGame server) since last year, and I always updated my MC Version, but today, I tried to join the server (on the 1.7.10, as I always did since it got released), and it shows me a message (i'll left a screen shot). I use Optifine and I think that was the problem, so I take it off, but It wasn't the problem. So I tried to connect with 1.8 (the server support this version too) and It works, but I don't use 1.8 'cause theres bugs on the server, nobody use 1.8 there. I don't know what to do. I'm Brazilian, so my english sucks. It's my first time in that website and this is my first question, so please, don't me mean. Please, help me :D[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow! Could you please read [this](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9943/how-do-i-ask-a-good-minecraft-bug-crash-question) and edit your question? Thank you

Answer (score -1):

if you still play this server try deleting and redownloading minecraft
and if you went to 1.8 on accident go there and check if your render distance is more then 16 :D

Comment: What does render distance have to do with that error message?